# WCF and Entity Framework . How to Create a Service Layer for all entities - Generically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf, generics

Ok so I am a bit lazy here. 
I want a Generic WCF service Layer to support my database functionality. I have a repository pattern for DB access - but in WCF from what I am reading it seems if I want to access each of these Entities - I need to create a Service Contract for each entity (I guess multiple endpoints.) As I do not want multiple hosts. WCF Data Services only supports webHTTPBinding and not Net.Tcp Binding. The DAL EF data POCO's are shared between client and service host. So is it possible to use Generics since the types are shared in both client and server? If so a small simple example should be enough to get me on my way.

Comment: I wouldn't create a service contract for each entity.  Group them by domain or logic or some other mechanism, and base your service contract(s) on that.

Comment: @Tim I am not quite following you; could you give me an example of how to do that - two simple entities for example Products and Orders  Dlayer.Products DLayer.Orders each has ID column and Name column. var Products = new Repository<Products>();

Comment: Just a FYI, you may want to look into [WCF Data Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2014/08/17/tutorial-sample-wcf-data-services-entity-framework-provider-is-updated-with-wcf-data-service-5-6-2/), it lets WCF communicate directly with your EF context.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: from my question ...
 WCF Data Services only supports webHTTPBinding and not Net.Tcp Binding. Which is why Data services is out.

Comment: Sorry, did not see that in the middle there. must of skipped the line when reading.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do here is break everything down into seperate libraries. You need to create seperate classes for the Service Contract, Service Interface, Data Layer and a Data Transfer Objects library.

You do this so that the Service Interface library can be shared on the client side and used to build a proxy using the ChannelFactory object and being passed a reference to the interface. (Dont use the "Add Service Reference" option in Visual Studio - build it yourself manually)

Doing this will enable to customise the proxy creation. What you cant do is make generic functions to access the service methods since the whole point of SOAP and WCF is that the methods form a solid contract between client and server. However, doing it this way will at least provide you with a way of sharing some of the burden between client and server in terms of code writing.

Miguel Castro offers up a good article here that explains the method: www.codemag.com/article/0809101